# data format string in grid view asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dataformat

Is there some way I can use a data format string in a bound field which appends % to my value ?

Example :

For rupee we can do this :

```
  <asp:BoundField DataField="PassPercent" ItemStyle-Width="7%" HeaderText="Pass Percent" DataFormatString="{0:c}"
```

I tried using a template field too but that didn't work :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pass Percent" ItemStyle-Width="5%" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" DataValueField="PassPercent"  DataTextField="PassPercent" />
                            <asp:Label Text="%" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: `DataFormatString="{0}%"` ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
DataFormatString="{0:p}"
```

But, please note percentages are stored as decimals in this case so you need to adjust your values accordingly. Check the formatting's here on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k).

Or you can simply hard-code it:-

```
DataFormatString="{0}%"
```

Comment: Can't delete ur comments :)