# How to display DateTime as Date when Convert.ToDateTime() was run first

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm stuck regarding a value I want to show. The problem is that I want to display in a GridView a Date value, but I can't parse it so it does that. I've tried to shrink the table column and several ways of parsing. Thank you so much for the help [As it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOJQN.png). And this is how it's parsed at the moment `reserva.Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["fecha"].ToString());`

Comment: How do you want the output to look?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't answer earlier. I'd like it to only show the date. The problem is with the parsing because the data from the database is formatted as a date

Comment: Can you please show the GridView source?

Comment: I´m sorry but it´s too long to post here, is it ok if I give you the GitHub link? https://github.com/frhgm/Serviexpress_Cliente/blob/master/CapaAccesoDatos/ReservaDAO.cs

Comment: Associate a format string with the column in the grid view (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764987/data-format-string-in-grid-view-asp-net-c-sharp). Leave the data as a DateTime, let the control format it. Look up the format options under the docs for `DateTime.ToString`

Comment: @FelipeRamírez I asked about view part... if you're using a `GridView` you need to add the string format for datetime, it should be something like `DataFormatString="{0:d}"`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm going to try that

Comment: I'm sorry @dbvega, the closest I have for that is Text='<%#Eval("Date") %>'. I'm not sure if that is what you mean

Comment: It will  be better if you attach an image displaying how are you initializing the GridView.

Comment: Thanks again @dbvega for trying, but is this what you mean? https://imgur.com/a/zCv6noN

Answer (score 0):

DateTime object has both date and time associated with it. If you want to display only the date part of it, use the `ToString()` to only show the date with formatting defined. [See Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1)

```
DateTime.Parse(dr["fecha"].ToString()).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

You can also use the method `ToShortDateString()` to display only the Date part of the DateTime object.

```
DateTime.Parse(dr["fecha"].ToString()).ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: It makes sense what you´re telling me, it should work, but it doesn´t. I'm just going to look like an idiot, but now it´s telling me that I cant convert a string to DateTime(With the second option you gave me)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the table I created previously was unable (I think) of displaying the data I had (in a List object) I still can´t display it from the list I want, but it shows the data I tell it to, so for now it works. Finally, instead of using `<asp:TemplateField> <HeaderTemplate> <asp:Label` for my table, I used `<asp:BoundField>`. I'm sorry if i'm not clear enough on the explanation, but I do believe it was a problem caused by using code I didn't understand so I don´t think it would happen to anyone else. Thank you so much everyone https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fgca.jpg